# Modal Bootstrap e MVC C#

Tags: c#, bootstrap, mvc

Pessoal tenho uma `view` chamada Projetos que trás uma lista de projetos e preciso visualizar as informações/detalhe de cada projeto através de um modal `Bootstrap`. Então criei um botão que chama uma função `javascript` dentro da `view` Projetos:

```
 <a data-toggle="modal"  class="btn btn-default btnDetalhes" data-value="@item.Codigo">Details</a>


$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
              var id = $(this).data("value");
                $(".btnDetalhes").click(function () {
                    $("#conteudomodal").load("/Documentos/DetalhePrj/" + id, function () {
                       $('#myModal').modal("show");
                });
            });
       });
```

E essa função chama o modal `Bootstrap`:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" >
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="conteudomodal">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

e através do `load("/Documentos/DetalhePrj/")` chama o `controller` que retorna uma `partial view DetalhePrj`:

```
 public PartialViewResult DetalhePrj(int id)
    {
        string PRJCODIGO = id.ToString();         
        ClienteModels ClienteAtivo = (ClienteModels)Session["EmpresaAtiva"];
        PCIOSDIGITALSOAPClient soap = new PCIOSDIGITALSOAPClient();
        ProjetoModel projeto = new ProjetoModel();
        projeto.Codigo = PRJCODIGO;
        soap.Open();
        List<STRUCTPROJDETALHE> lista = soap.LSTDETALHEPRJ(projeto.Codigo, ClienteAtivo.Loja);
        List<DetalhePrjModel> model = new List<DetalhePrjModel>();


        foreach (STRUCTPROJDETALHE item in lista)
        {
            DetalhePrjModel document = new DetalhePrjModel();
            document.CodigoPrj = item.CODPRJ;
            document.Versao = item.VERPRJ;
            document.Coord = item.COORD;
            document.DescrPrj = item.DESPRJ;

            model.Add(document);
        }
        soap.Close();
        return PartialView("~/Views/Documentos/_DetalhePrj.cshtml", model);
    }
```

O problema é que ao clicar no `buttom` ele abre a Modal porém não trás nenhuma informação/detalhe do projeto(modal abre em branco). É como se não estivesse conseguindo chamar o `controller` mas já revisei e não sei aonde estou errando.

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Agora estou tentando passar dois valores através do buttom para o javascript:

```
<a data-toggle="modal"  class="btn btn-default btnDetalhes" data-value="@item.Codigo" data-value2="@item.Versao">Details</a>


    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });             
                $(".btnDetalhes").click(function () {
                    var id = $(this).data("value");
                    var vers = $(this).data("value2");
                    $("#conteudomodal").load("DetalhePrj/" + id, + vers, 
                       function () {
                       $('#myModal').modal("show");
                });
            });
       });
```

Só que a variável vers está com valor null, não está puxando o valor do buttom..
Não é possível passar dois valores através de um único buttom?

Comment: Você pode tentar mudar um pouco a sua chamada `ajax` e não usar o `load`, mas sim receber o retorno da chamada e jogar o retorno em **conteudomodal**, usando o `success`, sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: O seu `data-value` está com uma quebra de linha, verifique se foi só no post da resposta.

Comment: Debuguei e está chamando o controller e tudo mais, o problema é que a chamada ajax não está pegando o valor da variavel id do buttom, dá que a variavel id é undefined.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo só no post está com a quebra de linha. No código está certinho

Comment: O id não está pegando porque está fora do bloco de click do .btnDetalhes

Comment: @LeandroAngelo fiz o que você falou e funcionou. Obrigadaaa!!!

Comment: @EmanueleBaron Eu estava escrevendo a resposta com essa observação, mas queria saber se o seu atributo também não estava errado.

Comment: @EmanueleBaron, Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo ainda não consegui passar dois valores para o javascript, tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Mas a sua controller recebe dois parâmetros?

Comment: Recebe sim... `public PartialViewResult DetalhePrj(int id, int vers)`

Answer (score 0):

Você declarou a variável `id` que deveria receber o `data-value` do botão de detalhes fora do escopo do evento de clique do mesmo, então ao utilizá-la para compor a url no `.load()` ela está indefinida porque o `$(this).data("value")` não está referindo-se ao botão. Basta posicionar a declaração no local correto.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
  });
  //var id = $(this).data("value");
  $(".btnDetalhes").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("value");
    $("#conteudomodal").load("/Documentos/DetalhePrj/" + id, function() {
      $('#myModal').modal("show");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Então edite esses detalhes na sua pergunta, na sua view e controller